# How can I shorten ABS pipe to move a drain trap?

Tags: plumbing, basement, drain, sink, abs

What’s the right way to shorten an abs pipe. I’d like to move my basement  sink over 3 inches to make room for a wall.

Should I simply cut a chunk out of the Horizontal pipe and join the ends with a coupler ?

See attachment.

Thanks!

[image: basement sink ABS]

Comment: which direction are you moving the sink?

Comment: Towards the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the union on the trap can be loosened so the sink end of the trap can be swung on an arc, then you could cut out a piece in the horizontal section and reconnect with a rubber connector which would allow axial rotation and would allow some in and out repositioning to properly line up all the parts for a leak free drain. If the union on the trap is cemented (which it is NOT supposed to be), then I think you would have to redo much of the drain to get it properly positioned if you move it. If the white on the union is just joint compound, then it could just be wiped off. A union does not need any joint compound and certainly is not to be cemented.

Normally in the horizontal section there would be a slip joint with smaller tubing from the sink fitting inside slightly larger tubing going into the wall. This allows axial rotation and in-and-out translation needed to properly mate all parts.

EDIT
See this video https://youtu.be/hzLqWu4DNO0. The teflon tape is strictly  not necessary because the sealing of the slip joints is done by the plastic seals. But this video shows all the elements necessary to have a drain in which all the parts can be in the correct positions and angles. Also in the video the narrator incorrectly calls a slip joint a "union". The only union in the drain is on the wall side of the trap. There are two faces which are held together with a nut and there is no separate seal needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a coupler?

I would undo the u bend outlet, shorten and re tighten.

Comment: It’s seized together with abs cement.  Any tricks ?

Comment: The undersink plumbing is not supposed to be entirely rigidly cemented. The union on the trap is supposed to allow movement in a circle. The horizontal section toward the wall is supposed to have a slip joint which allows both in-and-out positioning and axial rotation. All three movements are required to achieve a leak free fit.

Answer (score 0):

That's about all there is to it.

Make sure you get an ABS coupling and the appropriate glue. PVC pipe glue won't work properly, and you don't want to mix ABS and PVC pipe pieces.